# Checking file existence without using an ExecuteScript processor

Tags: bigdata, etl, apache-nifi, cloudera

I was wondering whether it is possible to check if a file exists using in-built, premade NiFi processors only, excluding the ones that allow you to customize their behavior with code (e.g.: ExecuteScript).

A simple workaround I've already seen is to concatenate 2 PutFile processors: the first one without a replacement strategy (failure) or bulletin level, since it is a controlled error; and the second one with both activated.

However, this is a special use case where you have to put the file and want to know if you had to replace it, but if you just want to know if a file already exists, without actually putting the file, I cannot think of any clean way to do it (because removing it in case you put it doesn't look good to me).

I'd like to know your thoughts on this and I would be really thankful for any guidance.

As a side note, I am currently using NiFi 1.18.0, FYI. Although if you know of any other version where it is possible, I would really appreciate if you could let me know.

**EDIT:** I am referring to event-triggered ways to do it, in response of a FlowFile. I know we can use ListFile, but this processor does not accept upstream flows, so we would need to be running a parallel flow every few minutes to be able to compare a file that we want to put and if it already exists in the target output path.

Another example to better explain this idea:

We want to store the contents of a FlowFile with a *filename*, but only if the file does not exist yet in the specified path. And we only want to raise a bulletin in case there actually is any issue.
The PutFile processor can be put to *fail in case of conflict*, but it can also fail in case of *permission error* or *not being able to access an NFS* (in case it is the target path). If we disable the bulleting level of PutFile, we would not be able to know if the failure was due to a duplicate file or because we cannot perform the action.

Comment: Have you looked at the `ListFile` processor, this way you can check if a specific file exists and then do processing based on routing logic

Comment: Hi @DataWrangler, thanks for you answer. The thing is that ListFile is not event triggered, so you would have a ListFile triggered every certain time and some other processors to check if the input files exists. If NiFi had an event-driven ListFile I would not see any issue, but AFAIK there is no way to have an upstream attached to it.

Comment: Ok, so this process is not the start of the flow, you can check out the `FetchFile` processor and then make use of the `Relationships` this is more like a workaround

Comment: Yeah, that is something that I also thought could work well, but if the use case requires big files it could create a bottleneck. We would be loading files to NiFi just to check if they exist.

Comment: Script sounds like a good solution